# Почему некоторые слова употребляются только с "пренебрежительным" суффиксом "-инк" и аналогичными?

Tags: словообразование

Довольно известно стихотворение некоего Паши:

```
Срезают лазером сосули,
В лицо впиваются снежины.
До остановы добегу ли,
В снегу не утопив ботины?

А дома ждёт меня тарела,
Тарела гречи с белой булой;
В ногах – резиновая грела,
И тапы мягкие под стулом.

В железной бане – две селёды,
Торчат оттуда ложа с вилой.
Есть рюма и бутыла с водой,
Она обед мой завершила.

Я в кружу положу завары,
Раскрою «Кобзаря» Шевчены –
Поэта уровня Петрары
И Валентины Матвиены.
```

Так вот, мне интересно, почему все эти слова нельзя употреблять в той форме, что приведена в шуточном стихотворении, а используются в них только "пренебрежительные" суффиксы?

Comment: Стих написан "по приклу", и вряд ли заслуживает обсуждения - особенно в плане иноязычных фамилий. Разве что может служить концентрированным примером безграмотности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

РАЗБИРАЕМСЯ ПО ПОРЯДКУ

СОСУЛИ - нет такого слова в русском языке, так как суффикс УЛЬК , а не УЛЬ  используется при образовании существительных от глаголов: грязный - грязнуля, мама -мамуля, но висеть - висюлька, сосать - сосулька.

СНЕЖИНКА - суффикс ИНК.  Нельзя сказаь  "снежина" - это будет нечто  страшное, огромное, снежное (сравнить: рыба - рыбина).

БОТИНКИ, заимствованные из франц. языка (от botine), также без суффикса К будут казаться очень большими ботинищами.

ТАРЕЛКА - в 16 веке мы ещё пользовались "тарелями", но уже в 17 веке перешли на тарелки.

БУЛКА - круглая (сравнить: ball  - мяч), ГРЕЛКА - греет, ЗАВАРКУ - заваривают, в ТАПКАХ - топают по ковру, на ОСТАНОВКЕ наконец-то остановился автобус - здесь вполне серьезный суффикс К обозначает существительные/предметы, мотивированные прилагательными и глаголами. Также в ЛОЖКУ кладем кашу, а на ВИЛКУ навиваем (накручиваем) спагетти.

КРУЖКА - не кувшин, а  маленький кувшинчик (кружьк), сравнить: kruz (польск) - кувшин.

БУТЫЛКА - не бочка, а маленькая бочечка (сравнить: butelka (польск) - бутылка, исх. butis (лат.) бочка.

БАНКА - тоже круглая, выпуклая, заимствована из польского: bania - выпуклый  сосуд, небольшая такая баночка/ванночка, родственная лат. бане (balneum  - баня, купальня).

СЕЛЁДКА - разговорная "сельдь", суффикс К позволяет правильно выговорить, а также услышать,  это слово.

Да, еще же РЮМКА, как без нее: "выпили и рюмки побили" (1698 год). Рюмки появились в Петровское время, заимствованы из голландского языка (roemer - бокал, рюмка) и переделаны из ромеров/ремеров в общепонятное слово. А до этого были еще  "ромишки"(др.-рус.) - небольшие римские чары/чарки.

ВЫВОД

Всё в языке очень правильно и серьезно, пренебрежительные суффиксы отсутствуют, а уменьшительные используются исключительно при необходимости.

Comment: Необязательно от глаголов - мамулька, бабулька.

Comment: Мама - мамуля - мамулька, суффикс ЛЬ+К.

Comment: От  нашей  вилки  до  итальянских  спагетти  очень  далеко,  хотя  связь  с  глаголом  "вить"  проследить  можно.  Скорее,  вилка  это  маленькие  вилы.  В  вилке  как  и  в  булке  -к-  уменьшительный  суффикс.

Comment: Слова  "сосуля"  в  словарях  нет,  а  языке  она  есть ( хоть  улыбает  в  официальной  речи ),  если  ребёнок  попросит  отломать  ему  "эту  сосулю",  никаких  вопросов  у  меня  не  возникло  бы.

Answer (score 4):

У некоторых слов "большой" аналог есть, но в другой форме: *бутылка-бутыль, ботинки-боты, вилка-вилы* и др.

Другие слова имеют смысл, только если маленькие: большую *сосульку* не пососешь, а большой *ложкой* в рот не положишь.

Третьи, просто по не всегда ясным причинам сложившаяся форма: *булка* и пр.

Про имена собственные думаю и так понятно.

В общем - так сложилось.

Answer (score 4):

Основное и главное.

Суффикс К (как и большинство других) в русском неоднозначный. 
Во многих случаях он не несет никакого уничижительного значения. Может быть диминутивными, субстанвивирующим (от глагола) и еще много чем - сравните: веревка, кошка, сарделька... Еще примеры - ниже.
В большинстве ваших слов у суффикса именно такая, "альтернативная" семантика.

//-------------------------

@София

> СОСУЛИ - нет такого слова в русском языке, так как суффикс УЛЬК , а не УЛЬ используется при образовании существительных от глаголов: грязный - грязнуля, мама -мамуля, но висеть - висюлька, сосать - сосулька.

Писуля, замазуля, сосуля(!), хохотуля...
©Лопатин

> СНЕЖИНКА - суффикс ИНК. Нельзя сказаь "снежина" - это будет нечто страшное, огромное, снежное (сравнить: рыба - рыбина).

снежина
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%F1%ED%E5%E6%E8%ED%E0

лещина, мужчина и т.д. - отнюдь не увеличительное.

> БОТИНКИ, заимствованные из франц. языка (от botine), также без суффикса К будут казаться очень большими ботинищами.

А суффикс ли тут К?

> ТАРЕЛКА - в 16 веке мы ещё пользовались "тарелями", но уже в 17 веке перешли на тарелки.

Это весьма спорный пример. Происхождение слова "тарелка" весьма своеобразно, вычление суффикса под большим вопросом.

> КРУЖКА - не кувшин, а маленький кувшинчик (кружьк), сравнить: kruz (польск) - кувшин. 
>   БУТЫЛКА - не бочка, а маленькая бочечка (сравнить: butelka (польск) - бутылка, исх. butis (лат.) бочка.
>   БАНКА - тоже круглая, выпуклая, заимствована из польского: bania - выпуклый сосуд, небольшая такая баночка/ванночка, родственная лат. бане (balneum - баня, купальня).

Во всех трех случаях диминутивность сомнительна. Скорее всего просто - субстантивирующий суффикс. Сюда же - РЮМКА.

> СЕЛЕДКА -
>   Ну уж не знаю, чем сельдь хуже для фонетики...

Я думаю, тут просто сказалось тяга русского языка к превращению слов по известной модели - столовка, вытрезвиловка, морковка, картошка...

Comment: Сосуля и писуля - этими словами пусть Лопатин сам пользуется, я ориентировалась на толковый словарь словообразовательных частиц,  тогда надо все словари переписывать, например раз в год. Суффикс ИН - многозначный, поэтому есть лещина с мужчиной, но одно из его значений - увеличительное, и его нужно исключить. А про фонетическую селедку - это отчасти шутка, которую не поняли, сельдь походит на термин (добыча сельди), в разговорной речи неудобна. Kruz и butis  уже субстантивированные, куда дальше. И т.д., можно разбираться по второму кругу. Или не стоит, учитывая юморист. жанр стиха.

Answer (score 1):

Подобная трансформация слов зачастую встречается в подростковой и молодёжной среде, так как в этом возрасте человек стремится к преувеличению значимости вещей и поступков, к новизне, к революции, в том числе и в своей речи. С возрастом подобные романтические настроения у большинства людей тонут в бытовой и социальной рутине, человек стремится передавать объективную информацию, «приземляется» и более не выходит за рамки правил речи и поведения.